# Classes won't swap using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, class

I'm trying to create something where you click on an image and it simply get's replaced with another image of the same dimensions.

I can almost get this working with the jQuery below, however it isn't changing the classes properly. The 'before' image has a class where :hover changes it's opacity. Once clicked I don't want the image to do the same, so I have created a second class for the 'after' image. However it just won't change classes.

HTML:

```
<div id="vote">
  <img src="images/icon-voteheart2.png" class="heart" />
  <h2>12</h2>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(function() {
    $('.heart').click(function() {
        $(".heart").fadeOut('fast');
        $(".heart").fadeIn('fast');
        $(".heart").attr('src', "images/icon-tick.png");
        $(this).removeClass(".heart");
        $(this).addClass(".heartnew");
        return false;
    });
  });
< /script>
```

Comment: What does happen when this click handler is run?

Answer (score 5):

Your class name isnt .heart its just heart. The . infront of class names is only used for CSS selectors, not in add or remove class

Answer (score 0):

Since the `heart` class is being dynamically generated and removed, you need to use the `live` function

```
$('.heart').live("click", function() {
   //etc
});
```

Additionally, `.heart` is not the name of the class. You need to change

```
$(this).removeClass(".heart"); 
$(this).addClass(".heartnew");
```

to

```
$(this).removeClass("heart"); 
$(this).addClass("heartnew");
```

Answer (score 0):

These two lines are wrong.

```
    $(this).removeClass(".heart");
    $(this).addClass(".heartnew");
```

When using [removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) and [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), do not include the dot.  It should be like this:

```
    $(this).removeClass("heart");
    $(this).addClass("heartnew");
```

Comment: @Richard James ... Your Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Your class name is "heart", so your selectors `$(".heart")` are correct, but when you use the `addClass`, `removeClass`, and `toggleClass` methods, use the actual class name: `addClass("heart")`.